# Click able search with ID

Tags: php, mysql

Help
I have a search with a clickable link which sends you to another page to view full results, But cant seem to get the ID into /searchclick.php?id=

Code for search

```
 // Build SQL Query  
$query = "SELECT Bird_ID, Species from Birds where Species like \"%$trimmed%\" order by   Species";

 $numresults=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($numresults);

if ($numrows == 0)
 {
  echo "<h4>Results</h4>";
  echo "<p>Sorry, your search: " . $trimmed . " returned zero results</p>";


  }

// next determine if s has been passed to script, if not use 0
  if (empty($s)) {
  $s=0;
  }

 // get results
  $query .= " limit $s,$limit";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
  echo "<br />";
   // display what the person searched for

 echo "<br />";
 echo "<p>You searched for: &quot;" . $var . "&quot;</p>";

 // begin to show results set
   echo "<br />";
   echo "<br />";
   echo "Results";
   echo "<br />";
   $count = 1 + $s ;


  // now you can display the results returned
 echo "<center>";
 echo '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">';
 echo '<tr><th>Bird_ID</th><th>Species</th><th>Comments</th></tr>';
 while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo '<td><a href="searchclick.php?id=">'.$row['Bird_ID'].'</a></td>';
 echo '<td>'.$row['Species'].'</a></td>';
 echo '<td>'.$row['Comments'].'</a></td>';
 $count++ ;
  }
```

The code for the clicked results

```
 session_start();
 include '/home/wc002/include/dbconnect.php';
 // get value of id that sent from address bar
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 // Retrieve data from database
 $query = "SELECT Bird_ID, Species, Comments, Image FROM Birds WHERE Bird_ID = '$id'";
 echo "<br />";
 echo '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" width="100">';
 echo '<tr><th>Bird ID</th><th> Species </th></tr>';
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Bird_ID'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Species'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['Image'] . "</td>";
 echo "</td>";
  }
 ?>
```

Thank you in advances

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, yet `href="searchclick.php?id="` means that `id` will always be empty. You should append your actual id after the equal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<td><a href="searchclick.php?id=">'.$row['Bird_ID'].'</a></td>';
```

You're not actually putting the ID in the link. Try this:

```
echo '<td><a href="searchclick.php?id='.$row['Bird_ID'].'>'.$row['Bird_ID'].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: DOH.. WORKS ..Thanks mate really appreciate it. :)